# When setting local-storage items in loop only even numbers get added

Tags: local-storage

Please consider the following code and output.  I have no idea why it's only processing keys with even numbers at the end.  Any ideas on why it's not processing the keys with odd numbers at the end?  I'm seeing this in IE 11.

```
try {
    localStorage.clear();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var item = 'ir360-grid-' + i;
        localStorage.setItem(item, 'test');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        console.log('processing key ' + key);
        if (key.startsWith("ir360-grid")) {
            console.log("removing: " + key);
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

---

```
processing key ir360-grid-0
removing: ir360-grid-0
processing key ir360-grid-2
removing: ir360-grid-2
processing key ir360-grid-4
removing: ir360-grid-4
processing key ir360-grid-6
removing: ir360-grid-6
processing key ir360-grid-8
removing: ir360-grid-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happens on Chrome too.

I'm pretty sure that happens because `localStorage` is an `Object` and not an `Array`.

On every iteration you decrement the length of localStorage so you only loop half the times you expected, and since localStorage is an Object the keys do not change according to the index.

So it goes like this:

```
i = 0
remove localStorage.key(0) // now ir360-grid-1 is at localStorage.key(0) and ir360-grid-2 is at localStorage.key(1)
i = 1  
remove localStorage.key(1) // which contains ir360-grid-2, now ir360-grid-3 is at key(1) and ir360-grid-4 is at key(2)
i = 2 
remove localStorage.key(2) // which contains ir360-grid-4 
and so on...
```

Using an `Object` iteration loop solves the problem:

```
for (var i in localStorage) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        console.log('processing key ' + key);
        if (key.startsWith("ir360-grid")) {
            console.log("removing: " + key);
            localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    }
```